# www.example.com loads, but example.com loads as an error on my WP multi-site network

Tags: wordpress, cms

I'm running an up-to-date version of a WP multi-site network successfully (homepage and subdomains all work), with only one problem.

My domain loads perfectly with the `www.`, but when the `www.` is not preceding, it loads up to this page: `http://www.example.com/wp-signup.php?new=example.com`.

I have never had this problem with WP before, so I'm looking for a way to fix this... Trying to make `www.example.com` and `example.com` load up the homepage fine, and be like my regular WP sites ending up in the address bar as `http://www.example.com/`

How can I achieve this? What must I edit?

Answer (score 2):

What web server are you running? If it's **Apache**, it's possible that you just need to add a `ServerAlias` to the domain's `VirtualHost` entry in your config.

You can add a `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`, so for example:

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
```

The `ServerAlias` will redirect to `ServerName`. Check the Apache [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive docs or the equivalent for your web server if not running Apache.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, safetycopy. I appreciate it! I'll be talking with my hosting admin about this!

Comment: You're welcome - hope it helps!

Comment: Hi safetycopy, your answer wasn't the solution, but I appreciate the help nonetheless!!